# JAVA setTitle dynamically

Tags: java, timer

I want to change the title dynamically by using a timer executed in the main form USERGUI.

The first execution of the timer is as follows:

```
public void startTimer(GUI gui, String staticTitle) {
    //this.gui = gui; 
    stayingTitle = staticTitle;
    timer = new Timer();
    myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
    int millisek = 1000; 
    timer.schedule(myTimerTask, millisek, millisek); 
}
```

In the running function of the timer it is defined as:

```
long hours = minuntilrecon / 3600;
long minutes = (minuntilrecon % 3600) / 60;
long seconds = minuntilrecon % 60;

String timeString = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
String setthisTitle = stayingTitle+" | Time left: "+ timeString;
UserGUI.newTitle(setthisTitle);
minuntilrecon = Math.abs(minuntilrecon-1000);
```

The timer should execute every second the following function in USERGUI:

```
public void newTitle(String gottitle){
    this.setTitle(gottitle);
}
```

But all I get in the console is a null pointer exception for the line with `UserGUI.newTitle(setthisTitle);`.

> Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at gui.TimerTitle$MyTimerTask.run(TimerTitle.java:74)
>   at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

Any idea?

Comment: Where is your object `UserGUI` ? why do you need to call `newTitle`, and inside call `setTitle`? why not just call `setTitle` directly?

Comment: UserGUI is definied in the top of the timer "public UserGUI UserGUI;". In fact I called setTitle in the beginning, then later I tried it by using the function.

Comment: Have you initialized `UserGUI` anywhere in the code, smt like `UserGUI = new UserGUI()` and making sure it is intialized **before** setTitle is being called? and the first character of variable's name should not be capitalized, it is bad practice. At least change it to `userGUI`

Comment: I thought I initialized UserGUI by "private UserGUI UserGUI;" (later I also tried public) in the top of the timer? Thanks, I will change the variable names later then to lower case.

Comment: It is not initialized, `UserGUI` is just declared, not initialized, in Java, you have to call `new` operator.

Comment: Everytime I initialize it it opens a new window instead of just changing the title. How can that be prevented?

Comment: Show us more code. I cannot tell anything with the current information :)